# How to remove all HTML tags with tidy

Tags: html, c++, c, tidy

I searched for a HTML parser and came up with [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).
The thing is that now that I have installed it I can't find how to strip all HTML tags (and also javascript function if its possible).
The example code turns html into XHTML and I'm starting to get a feeling that I have downloaded a not suitable package, couldn't find any documantation/manuals that explains it either.

Any suggestions on how this might be done with tidy?

EDIT:
As I understood tidy is an HTML parser, what I am trying to achieve is leave only the plain test i.e: `<h3>Test</h3>` will come up into `Test`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you are trying to do ... remove all HTML and JavaScript doesn't leave much.  Tidy is designed to restructure (organize) your code to make it more readable (yes, I know this is not a complete explanation).

Comment: @rfornal hi, please read the edit

Comment: Tidy is a parser in the sense that it works its way through the code, re-organizing it.  It does not strip the HTML ... in fact I'm not sure I've seen anything like this.

Comment: @rfornal if there is a library that can iterate over a webpage and understand the tags isn't it the simplest thing to add a string tags options? in the name of science?

Comment: Well, there's simple logic to you and me, then reality.  You could simply try loading the HTML page and copy the browser content from the browser ... then, paste text only into something like Word ... **simple**.

Comment: Can you use `jQuery('selector').text`?

Comment: @Andre hi, I am looking for c++ solution

Comment: Then don't tag your post `Javascript` :/

Comment: @Anton.P Then I don't think you'll find a workable solution. But you can write your own parser for that. Shouldn't take more than a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Tidy is basically is used to clean HTML pages. You can send the output of Tidy to libxml++ to parse the generated XHTML.

For a working example on using libxml++, look at this link
[Parsing a XHTML using libxml++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/ar01s02.html) You can use one of the 3 parsers to parse the string and get only text without any tags.